# How can I fit a matrix function with multiple variables to given eigenvalues?

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, fitting

I have a 5x5 matrix function `H[kx]`

```
H[kx_]:={{T1, kx T8, -I T6, kx T9, -I kx T10}, 
 {kx T8, T2, -I kx T11, kx T12, I kx T13}, 
 {I T6, I kx T11, T3, -I kx T14, kx T15}, 
 {kx T9, kx T12, I kx T14, T4, -I T7}, 
 {I kx T10, -I kx T13, kx T15, I T7, T5}
}
```

with real parameters `T1` to `T15`, and I have data as follow

```
dat={{-0.005, -0.418971, 1.24115, 2.6321, 3.07757, 4.40013}, 
 {-0.004, -0.418735, 1.24086, 2.63201, 3.07785, 4.40028}, 
 {-0.003, -0.418551, 1.24063, 2.63194, 3.07806, 4.4004}, 
 {-0.002, -0.41842, 1.24047, 2.63189, 3.07822, 4.40048}, 
 {-0.001, -0.418342, 1.24038, 2.63185, 3.07831, 4.40053}, 
 {0., -0.418316, 1.24034, 2.63184, 3.07834, 4.40055}, 
 {0.001, -0.418342, 1.24038, 2.63185, 3.07831, 4.40053}, 
 {0.002, -0.41842, 1.24047, 2.63189, 3.07822, 4.40048}, 
 {0.003, -0.418548, 1.24063, 2.63194, 3.07807, 4.4004}, 
 {0.004, -0.418728, 1.24085, 2.63201, 3.07785, 4.40028}, 
 {0.005, -0.418959, 1.24114, 2.63211, 3.07758, 4.40012}
}
```

For each `i`, `kx=dat[[i,1]]`, and `dat[[i,2;;6]]` are the eigenvalues (from small to big) which will be fitted by `H[kx]`.

The aim is to find all the parameters `T1` to `T15` which best produce the eigenvalues given by `dat` for all `kx`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The easy approach : define a measure of the deviation, for instance `expr = Total[
   Flatten[(ev[#[[1]]] - Reverse[SortBy[#[[2 ;;]], Abs]])^2 & /@ 
     dat]];` and then try to `NMinimize` it turns out to be unusably slow.

Comment: I did this, using an object function to describe the total deviation between the calculated eigenvalues and the data. And then using NMinimize or FindMinimum. However, the result is far from reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

Not having good starting values at hand, nor sufficient time to spare with your problem, here was the best I could do:

```
{mv, am} = 
 Quiet @ NMinimize[Norm[Norm[
   Map[Function[x, With[{kx = First[#]}, CharacteristicPolynomial[H[kx], x]] // Evaluate],
       Rest[#]]] & /@ dat],
                {T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15},
                Method -> {"NelderMead", RandomSeed -> 4}]
   {0.020097 + 0. I,
    {T1 -> 1.61337, T2 -> -0.418315, T3 -> 2.70502, T4 -> 3.47363,
     T5 -> 3.55875, T6 -> 0.73906, T7 -> 0.883149, T8 -> -5.58534,
     T9 -> 2.15443, T10 -> -1.25767, T11 -> 3.13062, T12 -> -1.82002,
     T13 -> 1.77503, T14 -> -0.694595, T15 -> -0.768617}}
```

Even this feeble attempt yields something usable:

```
mf[kx_] = H[kx] /. am;
Eigenvalues[mf[First[#]]] - Sort[Rest[#], GreaterEqual] & /@ dat
```

gives

```
{{0.00027062, 0.000618862, -0.00025875, -0.000162659, 4.80406*10^-6},
 {0.000107527, 0.000256957, -0.000105524, -0.0000752058, 3.12297*10^-6},
 {-0.0000226674, -0.0000167649, 0.0000136659, -2.74297*10^-6, 1.38639*10^-6},
 {-0.000109957, -0.00022229, 0.0000988083, 0.0000447379, 5.78009*10^-7},
 {-0.000164336, -0.000339608, 0.000159896, 0.0000672356, 6.90641*10^-7},
 {-0.000185798, -0.000378715, 0.000176925, 0.0000847389, 7.26231*10^-7},
 {-0.000164334, -0.000339608, 0.000159897, 0.000067227, 6.95853*10^-7},
 {-0.000109939, -0.00022229, 0.0000988172, 0.0000446694, 6.19705*10^-7},
 {-0.0000226064, -0.0000267654, 0.0000136958, -2.97409*10^-6, -1.47291*10^-6},
 {0.000107672, 0.000256956, -0.000105453, -0.0000657536, -3.5436*10^-6},
 {0.000280902, 0.00060886, -0.000268611, -0.000153729, -6.54493*10^-6}}
```

Someone with more time to play around with the `Method` option of `NMinimize[]` should be able to find better results than mine...